# SSRS Hidden dataset from parameter in query is missing

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, mdx

I haven't had this problem until now. I added an additional parameter in my MDX query (StrToSet(@Status)) and I expected SSRS to add a parameter and a hidden dataset automatically in their respected folders. But they are missing. I tried refreshing the dataset multiple times, but it is not working. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance, Olga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it with creating and adding the dataset myself and setting the parameter caption and value to the dataset. The parameter itself just wouldn't do it.